# Windows: Run script on cd

Tags: windows, command-line, script

On linux, I've got a number of scripts running upon changing to a directory. Tasks like updating repos, rotating logs, etc, are decided through a small bash script that overrides bash's "cd" and runs some of my scripts depending on which directory I'm changing to.

Over at my ubuntu, it looks a lot like this:

```
function cd() { 
  builtin cd "$@" && /home/cfv/scripts/changedir-hooks
}
```

All my efforts to overlap the existing "cd" on windows have been futile, and over at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074765/windows-run-script-upon-cd) I was told to come here and ask if perhaps I'm missing something somewhere.

To clarify, I understand I can have my own cd.cmd with some stuff in it, but I haven't been able to have it run *after* Windows's `cd`, and what I want to do is first change directory and `then` act upon that fact.

Can Windows do that?

Answer (score 0):

In [BASH Shell Command Search Sequence](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/an-example-how-shell-understand-which-program-to-run-part-ii.html), a *Shell FUNCTION* takes precedence over a *BUILTIN command*. There is no such concept implemented in Windows shell according to my best knowledge (although a `doskey` macro may resemble it): an [internal command](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) takes precedence over anything of the same name (see [Command Search Sequence](http://library.mobrien.com/manuals/mprm_group/command-console-shell.html)). So `cd [parameters]` displays the name of or changes the current directory always (see `cd /?`).

You could use either `cd.cmd [parameters]`, or rename your `cmd` script, see next example. This `cdn` script performs internal command `cd` and *then* changes current CLI window title to something like current directory path:

```
@rem cdn.bat
@rem change directory (and drive) || abort script processing in case of bad success
@cd /D %* || @goto :eof
@rem eliminate (if any in %*) trailing backslashes, surrouding double-quotes
@rem and/or (combined) symbols to current, parent or root directory (., .., \)
@call :window_title "%CD%"
@rem or, to title window to bare folder name, use: 
@rem @for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ("%CD%") do @title %%~nG%%~xG
@goto :eof

:window_title
  @if "%~p1%~n1%~x1" == "\%~n1%~x1" (
    @rem window title to 'X:\folder' on highest-level path or to 'X:\' on drive root
    @title %~d1%~p1%~n1%~x1
  ) else (
    @rem window title to 'X:\...\folder' otherwise (i.e. nor root, nor highest-level)
    @title %~d1^\ ..^\%~n1%~x1
  )
  @exit /B
```